# What is the Difference between Scheduling a Get Api call every single second, and Doing a Subscriber API?

Tags: java, scheduler, publish-subscribe

I  am Writing a Java Application where when the Data Changes an image should change,

My Colleagues are asking me to do a Scheduler where you have to call a get api every 1 second

My Suggestion is to use Pub-Sub so that whenever event happens , then only the data is changed

is Subscriber and Scheduler one and the Same?

No code

Comment: When using a `GET` request, you poll the data every second and validate if it has changed. When using publish/subscribe you only get notified when the data changes (no manual check required on your side). The second approach should be preferred due to lower network and resource consumption.

Comment: It sounds like you already know the main differences. Scheduling (polling) is simpler and easier to implement because the client decides if/when it needs data and the server simply responds to requests as usual. Publish/Subscribe is more complicated, you need additional subscribe/unsubscribe calls and the server needs to keep track of all subscribed clients.

Comment: @kapex sorry for off-topic.. is there any framework or libraries for pub/sub implementation on client/server architecture ?

Comment: @Ruslan There is Apache Kafka and Apache Pulsar. Most *message broker* frameworks also offer similar features. These are enterprise scale though and often overkill. I'm sure there are more lightweight frameworks/libraries that I don't know. Many server frameworks already integrate pub/sub solutions as well (for example I think Spring has JMS integration). For in-process pub/sub there are lightweight libraries like Guava EventBus.

Comment: @kapex thanks for detailed explanation

Comment: Let us say we have 2 applications , A Mobile App and a Web App Both Need to Talk to Each other. We are using Mobile Camera to do the gender and people count detection and that count and gender should be sent to a server, and as soon as there is a data change in the server, it should notify the application and based on that data there should be some changes in the web application, in this case what shall be used?

Answer (score 2):

Publish/subscribe is a nicer option, theoretically.

The differences:

- Polling is a kind of busy waits, with multiple clients causing superfluous network traffic. *The client is active.*
- Publish/Subcribe needs an active server that does a push notification to all subscribers. Meanwhile there is sufficient support in HTML5/JavaScript and in java. *The server is active.*

Unfortunately publish/subscribe will probably be a bit harder to realize. Best would be to make a *proof of concept* in a separate application. Things like asynchroneous Ajax might appear.

Also some publish/subscribe libraries might still use under the hood polling at the client side, instead of push notifications.

So the colleagues' advise might be based on the simpler, unproblematic implementation.

Depending on the leeway you are given, and in the interest of architectural research: a prototype with a load test for both implementations would be fine. *Hope never dies.*

Comment: [Usage](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/). I am no longer up-to-date with HTML5 nowadays. In the past there was talk of keeping the connection open, letting the brrowser a confirmation dialog for permitting push notifications. Theoretically a browser can either have a mostly blocked thread, waiting for the notification (best) or do a periodic polling. Look in the web for more & better info.

Answer (score 0):

It's no the same:

- Scheduler is when you explicitly choose when to make the request. You can to it every second, minute or whatever. Every time you create a new request.
- Pub-Sub is when you create a permatent connection to the source of events, and when an event is published you consume it. You don't have here multiple requests, it's rather a socket connection.